# SQL Select-IN query

Tags: sql

I have a numeric column named `id` in my table.
I want to select the queries which has id in 1,2,3 and the one which has 'null' in them.

I dont want to use the query like:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID IN (1,2,3) OR ID IS NULL
```

Can I use something like :

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,null)
```

Is this possible? The above query returns me the same result as for

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID IN (1,2,3)
```

Comment: When asking for correct syntax, it would help if you tell us which brand of SQL you're using ... :P

Comment: You have a query that works for you. Why don't you want to use that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using oracle, this may be solution.

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE NVL(ID,-1) IN (1,2,3,-1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Short answer? No. You must use the `IS NULL` predicate. NULL != NULL (two NULL values are not necessarily equal), so any type of `equals NULL`, `in (..., NULL)` is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

You must use:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID IN (1,2,3) OR ID IS NULL
```

NULL always requires the special handling of IS NULL.

Answer (score 0):

in sql server

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE isnull(ID,0) IN (1,2,3,0)
```